# Solve for x : $\sqrt{2}\sin(x)+\sqrt{6}\cos(x) = \sqrt{3} +1$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> Solve $\sqrt{2}\sin(x)+\sqrt{6}\cos(x) = \sqrt{3} +1$ for $x$

I started by multiplying both sides of the equation by $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ to obtain

$$\displaystyle\frac{\sin(x)}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos(x)}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3} +1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ $$\iff \sin(60+x) = \frac{\sqrt{3} +1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

I am stuck here. Any hints on solving the R.H.S will be appreciated.

Comment: You could also start by squaring both sides. You can then use double angle formulas to reduce to something that requires only the $30^\circ/60^\circ$ exact ratios. Bear in mind that squaring both sides is not a step that can be "undone" logically, so you will probably get some erroneous solutions. Just check them at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $\sin 75^\text o= \dfrac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt2}$

Can you find now ?

***PROOF :***

> $\sin (x+y)  = \sin x\cos y +\cos x \sin y  $
> $\sin(75^\text o) = \sin(30^\text o+45^\text o)\\\qquad\quad= \sin 30^\text o\cos 45^\text o +\cos 30^\text o \sin 45^\text o\\\qquad\quad = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2}+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2} = \dfrac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2} $

Answer (score 3):

Try to find what is $$\sin\frac{5\pi}{12}$$
If you get it $$\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}$$ then you did correctly and you know what to do next using the general definition of 
$$\sin x=\sin y $$ yields what you know it !

you can find $$\sin\frac{5\pi}{12}$$ using the formula for $$\sin \frac{x}{2}$$ by taking $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ in degrees which is equivalent to 75 degrees

Comment: Did you arrive at $\frac{5\pi}{12}$ using a calculator?

Comment: nope.. firest square it and notice what you get it after squaring .... you will get the idea. I know the formulas for sin 15 and sin 75 that's why i got it quickly.. i know half angle formulas... like for 22.5 also

Comment: if you think my solution wokrs for u .. please vote i will be obliged...

Comment: Cheers friend, an upvote from me  (+1)

Comment: @Ak19 thanks friend

Comment: You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{3} +1}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\sin{45^\circ}\cos{30^\circ}+\cos{45^\circ}\sin{30^\circ}=\sin{(45^\circ+30^\circ)}=\sin{75^\circ}$$

Answer (score 0):

square both sides, we get
$$2 \sin^2(x) + 6 \cos^2(x) + 2\sqrt{12}\cos(x)\sin(x) = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$
that is 
$$2 + 4 \cos^2(x) + 2\sqrt{12}\cos(x)\sin(x) = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$
that is 
$$2 + 4 \cos^2(x) + \sqrt{12}\sin(2x) = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$
that is 
$$2 + 4 \frac{1}{1+\tan^2(x)}  + \sqrt{12}\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2(x)} = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$
Multiply everything by $1 + \tan^2(x)$
$$2(1+\tan^2(x)) + 4   +2 \sqrt{12}\tan x = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2(1+\tan^2(x)) $$
This is quadratic in $y = \tan(x)$

$$ay^2 + by + c = 0$$
where 
\begin{align}
a &= 2- (1 + \sqrt{3})^2\\
b &=2\sqrt{12}\\
c &= 2 + 4 - (1 + \sqrt{3})^2
\end{align}
Solving you get something like
\begin{align}
y_1 &= 1.0000 \\
y_2 &= 0.2679
\end{align}

> Now taking the inverse tangent of that you get
>   \begin{align}
> x_1 &= \tan^{-1} y_1 =\tan^{-1} 1.0000  = 45^\circ\\
> x_2 &= \tan^{-1} y_2 =\tan^{-1}  0.2679= 15^\circ
> \end{align}

Comment: I think you missed multiplying 1+tanx on the R.H.S

Comment: right .. ill edit

Comment: @AhmadBazzi, it is overkill ! You could solve that equation more easily.